# Assembly: AVR Studio alternatives for Linux

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmel, assembly, assembler

I had been using using AVR Studio on Windows to write assembly code for my MCUs (mainly for atmega8515) for a couple years. However, recently I transitioned to Linux and turns out there aren't any official tools for writing programs for AVR controllers. There is a C compiler called avr-gcc, but I don't know C so I'd like to continue using assembly since I'm already familiar with it. I know you can use avrdude to flash controller's memory, but I can't find any tool that can transform .asm file to .hex file.

So here's my question: Is there any tool for Linux that takes .asm file as input and returns .hex file as output so I can directly flash it into my controller?

I decided to ask this question since other questions here that bring up this topic are 10 or more years old. Hope someone can help me find a solution, otherwise I'll have to run AVR Studio in wine or virtual machine. Thanks!

EDIT: Looks like avr-as is the tool I'm looking for, I just need to learn differences in syntax. Thanks!

Comment: That's not really an electrical engineering question. What research have you done before asking? Did you put "AVR assembler linux" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: Hi, Justme. Yes, I did exactly that, and unfortunately wasn't able to find something useful. Every link was either very old or unrelated to my question.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question and add the keyword lists of your searches and some examples of these unrelated findings. Perhaps you need to hone your web search skills, and presumably we can help you with _that_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

avr-gcc comes with an assembler, `avr-as`. Otherwise, you can also do inline assembly within a C program, which often if not a bad choice, because you can use the probably better-than-human-on-average code generation of a modern compiler (gcc 12 or 13, or even 14 at the time of writing, are really good at reducing logic to what is necessary and thus producing compact code) in your program. Even if not familiar with C, a simple loop with an exit condition might be something that is not that hard to learn to express in C99. For the parts of the firmware where you need cycle-accurate execution, building things in assembler stays an option, that way.

Anyways, no matter whether you use the C compiler with assembler embedded in C code, or the free-standing `gcc-as` assembler, avr-gcc has your back.

Comment: I tried using avr-as to assemble this code: https://pastebin.com/yHPrFmJq 
This is a simple blinking led program in assembly that worked fine in AVR Studio
However, avr-as failed to assemble it and instead gave me a lot of errors: https://pastebin.com/BS21M5vj
This is probably a really dumb question, but why is it not working?

Comment: @Heather7283 Different assemblers have different syntax; look up the manuals for your tools. Example: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html

Comment: The varying syntax of the different tools is irritating but no worse.  I've had very good results from both avr-gcc and avr-as directly.  To be explicit, the suite includes `avr-objcopy`, which makes hex files (of various kinds) which you can program to flash with `avrdude` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you should be able to use MPLAB X IDE.
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-x-ide#tabs
Step by step guide for AVR Asm is here:
https://microchipdeveloper.com/swtools:avr-asm:mplabx-project-setup

Comment: :0 Somehow I completely missed it... I'll definitely give it a try, thanks!